# How to build a name for a cell using a formula?

Tags: excel

I am creating a new scorecard using a data table and then I am using pivot tables to create pivot charts. There will eventually be 20 pages of charts. Each page of the scorecard (when viewed) will have four pivot charts.  In order to populate some information that appears below each pivot chart (some counts and whatnot), I also have a set of formulas, for each pivot chart / pivot table, that use the chosen pivot table filter values for the applicable pivot table to look up data in the table. I am trying to avoid using any absolute cell references in these formulas because I am building the pivot tables for the first page now and then will  copy that twenty times. I have three fields as filters for each pivot table.

I have "numbered" each graph so that the graph on the upper left is 1A, upper right is 1B, lower left is 2A, and lower right is 2B. I have those values in cells that I would like to use to assign a name to each filter in the pivot tables. In other words, cell Q1 contains "1A" and cell S1 contains the value "Insurance_2." I would like to assign the name "Ins_1A" to cell S1, and I would build the name using a concat formula.

I've tried using concat to 'build' "Ins_1A" in a free cell and then tried to add that to name manager and point it to S1, but that does not work. I want to be able to use the value that is built (for the first graph, that would be "Ins_1A") in my formulas instead of an absolute reference to $S$1 (which is currently necessary because I am using the same formula to pull 10 values from the data table and those formulas are in the same column).

I've created a sanitized version of my workbook because I realize the above it impossible to understand without seeing it. But, I don't see an obvious way to attach it. I'll continue to look.